# How to encapsulate logic in a createSelector function?

Tags: react-native, redux, reselect

I have a React Native app using Redux.

I want to be able to add an entry at the beginning of this list of projects
but it is not working.

Part of code provided below.

This is the error I get:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'projects.list.push')

Im not show of the correct syntax here??

Thanks in advance.

```
initialState: {
    list: [],
    loading: false,
    lastFetch: null,
  },


export const getPickerList = createSelector(
  (state) => state.entities.projects,
  (projects) => projects.list.push({ project_id: 0, project_name: "[All]" }),
  (projects) =>
    projects.list.filter((project) => ({
      project_id: project.project_id,
      project_name: project.project_name,
    }))
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you actually want to do this:

```js
export const getPickerList = createSelector(
  (state) => state.entities.projects,
  (projects) => {
    const projectsWithPrefix = [
      { project_id: 0, project_name: "[All]" },
      ...projects
    ];
    // you could filter here as well before returning
    return projectsWithPrefix 
  }
);
```

but honestly I have *no* idea what you were trying with that `.filter` there.

Generally, you cannot "chain" as you were thinking you were doing. All the return values of all functions except for the last one are passed as arguments into the *last* function, **not the next one**.

Answer (score 2):

You've got two bugs here, plus I think there's a conceptual problem.

The first is that **you are actively mutating `projects.list`**, by calling `projects.list.push()`.  [You must never mutate state when using Redux](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-mutate-state).

The second issue is that *all* input selectors get called with the *same* arguments.  So, if you call `selectSomeThing(state, "a', 42)`, *all* input selectors will get called with `state, "a", 42`.

That means that the second input selector's first argument is actually `state`, not `projects`.

The other problem is that a selector isn't the right place to "add" anything.  That sounds like a state update, and all state updates must happen in reducers.

Comment: Thanks I see what you are saying here. Im new to redux. Can I ask you then how would you do it? I want to add a option to the beginning of a projects lists that represents selecting "All" projects. Its a filter list.??